# The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([ID]), true]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where()

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, querying

can anyone help me structure this query everything works but as soon as I put the age range query it throws an error here's my query

```
                fireStore
                .collection('TestUsers')
                .where('Country', isEqualTo: 'Mexico')
                .where('ID', whereNotIn: [
                  '9f8fe3c0-83fb-11ec-ba7d-71eedc0beebe',
                  '3eb69ae0-83fa-11ec-b4a4-cba7e6a8918b'
                ])
                .orderBy('ID', descending: true)
                .where('DOB',
                    isLessThan: minAgeToQueryWith,
                    isGreaterThan: maxAgeToQueryWith)
                .orderBy('DOB', descending: true)
                .where('Gender', isEqualTo: 'Gender Fluid')
                .orderBy('BoostDate', descending: true)
                .orderBy('Points', descending: true),
```

this is the error I get

The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([ID]), true]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([DOB])' when an inequality operator is invoked.
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 677 pos 11: 'field == orders[0][0]'

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.
You must use .orderBy for the .where query

For Example

```html
_firestore
  .collection(_generalNotifications)
  .where('isDeleted', isNotEqualTo: true)
  .orderBy('isDeleted')
  .orderBy('sentAt', descending: true)
  .snapshots()
```

So here is your correction.

```html
fireStore
  .collection('TestUsers')
  .where('Country', isEqualTo: 'Mexico')
  .where('ID', whereNotIn: [
    '9f8fe3c0-83fb-11ec-ba7d-71eedc0beebe',
    '3eb69ae0-83fa-11ec-b4a4-cba7e6a8918b'
  ])
  .where('DOB',
      isLessThan: minAgeToQueryWith,
      isGreaterThan: maxAgeToQueryWith)
  .where('Gender', isEqualTo: 'Gender Fluid')
  .orderBy('Gender')
  .orderBy('DOB', descending: true)
  .orderBy('ID', descending: true)
  .orderBy('BoostDate', descending: true)
  .orderBy('Points', descending: true),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `where` in the first and the `orderby`in the last

solution is

```
fireStore
                .collection('TestUsers')
                .where('Country', isEqualTo: 'Mexico')
                .where('ID', whereNotIn: [
                  '9f8fe3c0-83fb-11ec-ba7d-71eedc0beebe',
                  '3eb69ae0-83fa-11ec-b4a4-cba7e6a8918b'
                ])
               
                .where('DOB',
                    isLessThan: minAgeToQueryWith,
                    isGreaterThan: maxAgeToQueryWith)
                .where('Gender', isEqualTo: 'Gender Fluid')
                .orderBy('BoostDate', descending: true)
                .orderBy('Points', descending: true)
                .orderBy('ID', descending: true)
                .orderBy('DOB', descending: true)
```

it must work , but if the fields of orderBy does not equal in logic then you need to put only  one .orderBy query

Comment: No doesn't work if I remove the boostDate and Points .orderBy it works but for DOB if I change from variable to int for example

.where('DOB',
                    isLessThan: 2004,
                    isGreaterThan: 1960)


it throws The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([ID]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([DOB])" when an inequality operator is invoked.
'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':
Failed assertion: line 485 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]'

Comment: ('DOB', isLessThan: 2004, isGreaterThan: 1960) you can only use one compare ! you can't use bath isLessThan, isGreaterThan

Comment: what can I do to get age range then im making a dating app where users can select the min and max age

I might be wrong but I think 
'Firestore query can only perform range filtering on a single field. '

and im doing range on single field

Comment: use it in separated orderby Method ,,Remember ,, data must equal the logic with all orderby you use and they were no revers in logic

Comment: I might be wrong but I think 
'Firestore query can only perform range filtering on a single field. '



Update :- also doing this

  .where('DOB', isGreaterThan: 2000)

throws the same error

and im doing range on single field

Comment: you can use  int list as local varible,  and throw on it the user inputs for example 18-25 years ..  then use where('age',whereIn : your List here ) ,, better to make conditions b4 user inputs for example a ready list that contains all wanted agses ..simple

Comment: Tried that before too didn't worked

I even tried notEqualto [AgeNumberList] and whereIn[AgeNumberList]. neither worked

Comment: it is !! ,, edit your question of wanted method exactly please

Comment: if something you did worked kindly provide me the code that you have actually tested so I can try on my end too that would be helpful thanks tho